# eBPF verifier: R1 is not a scalar

Tags: ebpf, cilium, tracepoint

I have this eBPF code:

```c
struct sock_info {
    struct sockaddr addr;
};

SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_accept4")
int sys_enter_accept4(int fd, struct sockaddr *upeer_sockaddr, int *upeer_addrlen, int flags) {
    struct sock_info *iad = bpf_ringbuf_reserve(&connections, sizeof(struct sock_info), 0);
    if (!iad) {
        bpf_printk("can't reserve ringbuf space");
        return 0;
    }
    // https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html
    bpf_probe_read(&iad->addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr), upeer_sockaddr);
    bpf_ringbuf_submit(iad, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to load it from the user space, the Cilium eBPF library returns me this Verification error:

```
permission denied
R1 is not a scalar
; int sys_enter_accept4(int fd, struct sockaddr *upeer_sockaddr, int *upeer_addrlen, int flags) {
0: (bf) r6 = r2
R2 !read_ok
processed 1 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0
```

If I remove the `bpf_probe_read` function, then the code runs. I tried many alternatives to try to read the contents of the `*upeer_sockaddr` pointer, but did not succeed.

Any hint why the eBPF verifier is complaining?

This is the output of `llvm-objdump` command:

```
llvm-objdump -S --no-show-raw-insn pkg/ebpf/bpf_bpfel.o

pkg/ebpf/bpf_bpfel.o:   file format elf64-bpf

Disassembly of section tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_accept4:

0000000000000000 <sys_enter_accept4>:
       0:   r6 = r2
       1:   r1 = 0 ll
       3:   r2 = 16
       4:   r3 = 0
       5:   call 131
       6:   r7 = r0
       7:   if r7 != 0 goto +5 <LBB0_2>
       8:   r1 = 0 ll
      10:   r2 = 28
      11:   call 6
      12:   goto +7 <LBB0_3>

0000000000000068 <LBB0_2>:
      13:   r1 = r7
      14:   r2 = 16
      15:   r3 = r6
      16:   call 4
      17:   r1 = r7
      18:   r2 = 0
      19:   call 132

00000000000000a0 <LBB0_3>:
      20:   r0 = 0
      21:   exit
```

Answer (score 3):

You have defined your tracepoint program with 4 arguments `int sys_enter_accept4(int fd, struct sockaddr *upeer_sockaddr, int *upeer_addrlen, int flags)`

But these are not the parameters with which your program will be invoked.

The `R2 !read_ok` error is caused because you are accessing a second, non-existing parameter and you are not allowed to read from uninitialized registers.

For tracepoints you can find out the context structure by looking at the sysfs:

```
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_accept4/format
name: sys_enter_accept4
ID: 1595
format:
    field:unsigned short common_type;   offset:0;   size:2; signed:0;
    field:unsigned char common_flags;   offset:2;   size:1; signed:0;
    field:unsigned char common_preempt_count;   offset:3;   size:1; signed:0;
    field:int common_pid;   offset:4;   size:4; signed:1;

    field:int __syscall_nr; offset:8;   size:4; signed:1;
    field:int fd;   offset:16;  size:8; signed:0;
    field:struct sockaddr * upeer_sockaddr; offset:24;  size:8; signed:0;
    field:int * upeer_addrlen;  offset:32;  size:8; signed:0;
    field:int flags;    offset:40;  size:8; signed:0;

print fmt: "fd: 0x%08lx, upeer_sockaddr: 0x%08lx, upeer_addrlen: 0x%08lx, flags: 0x%08lx", ((unsigned long)(REC->fd)), ((unsigned long)(REC->upeer_sockaddr)), ((unsigned long)(REC->upeer_addrlen)), ((unsigned long)(REC->flags))
```

If we turn this into a structure we get the following:

```c
struct accept4_args {
  u64 pad;

  u32 __syscall_nr;
  u32 fd;
  struct sockaddr *upeer_sockaddr;
  int *upeer_addrlen;
  int flags;
};
```

Note that I replaced the common_ fields here with `u64 pad`, since that is likely not what you are interested in.

A pointer to the struct is passed in as one parameter: `int sys_enter_accept4(struct accept4_args *args)`

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much for the extensive explanation. Do you know if there is any documentation explaining this behavior?

Comment: No official docs that I know of, I based the answer on this sample: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/samples/bpf/cpustat_kern.c